# Firebase: How to see retention month by month?

Tags: firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I trying to see my app retention month by month but it is impossible in firebase and in google analytics, how can I do it ?

Like you can see it is day by day

[image]

And I want something like this but not by week

[image]

Comment: go to google analytics, left hand side Reports > Retention > Top right there are dates, click them and you can change the range

Comment: I did it but I only can see it day by day

Comment: In the image you posted it is Month by Month unless I'm not understanding your question

Comment: No on the first screen it is day by day. I want to see if a user is active x month after his download, not just 30 day after. I don't know if it is clear

Comment: The second image is exactly what I want but in weekly, not monthly

Comment: After looking it up, I don't believe its possible

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this too and was baffled that it didn't exist "out of the box". But you can do the following:

Inside Firebase Analytics Dashboard:

1. Click "View more in Google Analytics" (unless you already are at the Google Analytics webpage)
2. Now from left-side panel press "Explore"
3. Click "Blank" (will create a new "Exploration")
4. Next to the "Free form 1"-tab there should be "+" sign, press it
5. Click "Cohort exploration" (1. in image)
6. Now change "Cohort Granularity" to Monthly (from Daily/Weekly) (2. in image)

[image]

Voila! Bit of a pain but it works...