# Firebase Analytics retention analysis by day

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

How to view Retention Analysis in Firebase Analytics by day?
I only see by weeks, I want 1 day for example 20% 2 day 10% , for each day so that the retension can be seen.

[image: by week]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for this too and was baffled that it didn't exist "out of the box". But you can do the following:

Inside Firebase Analytics Dashboard:

1. Click "View more in Google Analytics" (unless you already are at the Google Analytics webpage)
2. Now from left-side panel press "Explore"
3. Click "Blank" (will create a new "Exploration")
4. Next to the "Free form 1"-tab there should be "+" sign, press it
5. Click "Cohort exploration" (1. in image)
6. Now change "Cohort Granularity" to Daily (from Weekly) (2. in image)

[image]

Voila! Pain but it works...

I believe this is a similar question as this: [Firebase: How to see retention month by month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70217165/firebase-how-to-see-retention-month-by-month/74823137#74823137)